# How to debug when breaked

Tags: c++, debugging

I have problem when debug program in VS 2012, my program is break and i got notice:

Unhandled exception at 0x7540EE99 (user32.dll) in Win32_Timer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFF4AF0.

Like this:

[image]

I don't ask for this situation, but because I meet that error several times, so I want to know HOW TO CHECK / FIX WHEN DEBUG IS BREAK (principle and how steps to resolve).

Thank in advance !!!

Comment: It looks like you are supplying an invalid pointer to SetWindowText. How do you initialize wParam?

Comment: While debugging you should be able to see the stack trace to see where in your code the exception was thrown from.

Comment: ... and set break points